# Using OneDrive for multiple clients possible?

Tags: office365, onedrive

A networking representative on my project plans to save documents for different clients in their own folders on OneDrive through Office 365. The clients will then login into a website I create with their credentials and get their documents based on their login id from the sql table.

Is this best practice for OneDrive?  Would it be better to have the documents uploaded through the website by an admin and programmatically save the file to a directory created by code on the web server. With correct client credentials, the database will match client id to folder in directory.

We could save the files to OneDrive as backup and not where files would be retrieved from.

An admin having access to folders through Office365 rather than an application handling the process may not be a good practice?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue to store your client information on OneDrive and set proper permissions per document or folder. The web app also can utilizes the OneDrive API to retrieve the documents that are shared to the user once he logs in using his credentials.

You don't need to duplicate the locations for your documents, since all files in OneDrive are secured based on the permissions you set or share with others.

Hope this helps.